# What is the difference between spring-context and spring-core dependencies?

Tags: spring, maven, dependencies, spring-context

Hello I am new to the Spring and maven world, and I want to know what is the difference between this 2 dependencies?

Its a simple question.. I am having trouble with my `pom.xml` file, so I want to know everything :).

Thanks  in advance.

Comment: http://www.javajazzup.com/issue1/page23.shtml might be a start, but please post your problem

Answer (score 49, accepted):

These are actually 2 of many Spring Framework modules. You can easily find what packages these artifacts contain, using this site:

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core/3.1.1.RELEASE

This can give you information about classes contained within a particular artifact and probably about the its purpose.

For Spring Framework, `spring-core` contains mainly core utilities and common stuff (like enums) and because it's really critical for Spring, probably all other Spring modules depend on it (directly or transitively).

In turn `spring-context` provides Application Context, that is Spring's Dependency Injection Container and it is probably always defined in POMs of artifacts that use Spring Framework somehow. In fact, `spring-context` depends on `spring-core` so by defining `spring-context` as your dependency, you have `spring-core` in your classpath as well.

Comment: So, `spring-core` and `spring-context` two separate dependencies is not need iin the same application?

Comment: Probably they are, actually. As I explained, if you depend on `spring-context`, you depend on `spring-core` as well.

Comment: They are two different dependencies.  As @Michał wrote, `spring-context` depends on `spring-core` so, Maven will get it as a transitive dependency. You can see such dependencies in `spring-context` Maven repository site: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context/5.1.5.RELEASE  
So, `spring-core` is under **Compile Dependencies**, meaning that if you include `spring-context` in your POM file, you will also get `spring-core` as well, (...among others).

Comment: `and probably about the its purpose` ??

Comment: `and it is probably always defined` ??